# Remote Office 365 worker - laptop lockdown

Tags: security, sharepoint, encryption, laptop

We have a small Office 365 tenant of about 20 users, mix of E3 and Business Essentials.  We are now migrated from a local LAN file server to SharePoint Online and OneDrive so would like to move the few remote workers from a Dial-in VPN/RDP setup to being solely connected to Office 365 on Windows 10 (company owned) laptops and iOS devices from wherever they choose to work.

I have a concern about the local caching of Sharepoint files and email to the laptop if a user loses the laptop or is suspended/terminated.  Is it possible by just adding 'Enterprise Mobility + Security E3' licences to these user's accounts (not the entire organisation) to remotely lock, encrypt, and in extreme circumstances wipe the devices remotely from the O365 Admin portal?

Any advice would be appreciated.